# Meld - Failed To Register

Tags: meld

I use Meld very frequently and it just started bailing on me today. When I try to run meld from commandline, it stalls for some time and then exits with `Failed to register: Timeout was reached`.

I did an `apt remove`, `apt update` and re-install and the issue is still there.

Any suggestions on debugging this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who hit this issue, try restarting your machine. I found a [closed ticket](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/issues/434) on the meld issue tracker and tried it and sure enough, the issue went away.

Comment: Awesome! Not a wildly insightful/technical link; but, it makes the answer complete. We need more responsive users, like you, here!

Comment: Link says that a reboot made the issue go away, but doesn't work for me, still exits with timeout was reached error even after reboot.

Comment: @Hedede - I would recommend raising a ticket for this then as it seems you may have a different, but related, problem. Issue Tracker: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld

Comment: wondered why for many people a reboot is an acceptable solution...

Answer (score 19):

Likely there's a meld process that hung in the background and wouldn't quit.  Just kill the meld process with SIGTERM (or SIGKILL if SIGTERM doesn't work).  No need to restart the machine.

Comment: Thanks! Restarting my machine is very rarely the correct solution. We're not running Windows here, right?!

Comment: I understand that problem is related to some dbus resources ?

Observing problem on KDE

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/issues/669

Comment: For the newbies: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/how-can-i-kill-a-process-by-name-instead-of-pid-on-linux), that answers how to kill a process by name, might help. I used `pkill -f "meld"` and meld worked again.

Comment: Note: `killall meld` doesn't work for this because meld is run via Python, so the command name doesn't match. See also: [What's the difference between pkill and killall?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91527/6764)

Comment: This can happen if your display server crashed. For some reason Meld isn't sensitive enough to its display server socket dying and can stay running after this happens. Especially true when running under Plasma 6 with its kwin composer recovery: after the composer recovers, Meld will not reconnect and will stay running without a window.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for suggestions on how to debug this. So here's how I debugged this: I ran `sudo meld` and it worked. I then ran `sudo su username` for my username and meld worked in that window. Then I ran a `env > blah.txt` in the working window and `env > blah_busted.txt` in the broken window. I pulled up `meld blah.txt blah_busted.txt` to do a diff and began running `unset VAR_NAME` for each variable name that was defined in the busted.txt but not in the good one. Finally I ran:

```
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

And meld magically worked again.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 via X2GO. I also had to 'unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' in ~/.bashrc to get anything snap related to run via x2go. That's a known issue with x2go. It seems ubuntu does no regression testing via x2go, and I can't find any documentation on how/if ubuntu regression tests at all.

Comment: Very creative troubleshooting @poleguy! I will give that a try if I see that issue again.

Comment: I had the same problem with gthumb, unsetting the DBUS variable seems to have solved it.  Thanks!